# Unable to initiate the replica set for config server of sharded MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am following [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) link to deploy a sharded cluster. In the first step as they have told I have started three separate mongod instances as

```
mongod --configsvr --replSet “cs” --dbpath mongodb/config/config-c --bind_ip localhost --port 57042
mongod --configsvr --replSet “cs” --dbpath mongodb/config/config-c --bind_ip localhost --port 57042
mongod --configsvr --replSet “cs” --dbpath mongodb/config/config-c --bind_ip localhost --port 57042
```

After that in step two, when I try to initiate Replica set as they have mentioned like this

```
rs.initiate( { _id: "cs", configsvr: true, members: [ { _id : 0, host : "localhost:57040" }, { _id : 1, host : "localhost:57041" }, { _id : 2, host : "localhost:57042" }]})
```

I am getting an error

```
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Attempting to initiate a replica set with name cs, but command line reports “cs”; rejecting",
    "code" : 93,
    "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig",
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")
    },
    "lastCommittedOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error ? How to solve this ?

Comment: You got smart quoted!  Remove the quotes from the command line, or replace the smart quotes with regular quotes (`"`)

Comment: This is in the starting "mongod" or the rs.initiate() command ?

Comment: I'm talking about `--replSet “cs”` notice that these don't look like `"` they are a different character that is being interpreted as part of the name.